# MVVM Xamarin Forms Design

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

So I was looking at https://github.com/xamarin/Sport as an example I came across when googling something for my current project. It is similar to what Im working on because I use an azure backend as well.

I have a question about their mvvm layout. I thought that in mvvm the models were sort of POCOs and not supposed to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Arent they acting as both a Model and a ViewModel in this case? Look at the Athlete model and the AthleteViewModel. The VM has a property for for Athlete and so the model is used as a VM as well.

In my project, if I had the same types, I would have an Athlete model, an AthleteViewModel and an AthletePageViewModel. Where the Athlete and AthleteVM would be automapped. The only reason to populate and or create the Athlete is to persist it to the service or local storage.

Is one way more "correct" than the other way? Or am I just doing it wrong and over complicating it? I almost don't want to continue with the way I'm doing it because I dont want to have a bunch of "extra" model files if I can just use some of my VMs as models.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no ultimate master set of strict rules that you need to follow in order to implement the MVVM design pattern. In fact, the guidelines are generally quite *blurry*.

From what I've seen, there are a couple of different methods of which a model may be exposed to the view. Here they are:

**Method 1 - INotifyPropertyChanged in the Model**

```
public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Model;

    public string Model
    {
        get { return _Model; }
        set 
        { 
            _Model = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    ...
}

public class CarViewModel
{
    //The entire model is exposed to the view.
    public Car Model { get; set; }
    ...
```

**Method 2 - INotifyPropertyChanged in the View Model**

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    private Car _Car;

    //The model property is exposed to the view, not the model itself.
    public string CarModel
    {
        get { return _Car.Model; }
        set 
        { 
            _Car.Model = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
    ...
```

In terms of a *preferred* method, I would say method 2 is the better option. Why?

- The Model object is not exposed to the view.
- The View Model only exposes what the View needs.

Method 2 does have its downsides. Imagine if you needed to expose **lots** of model properties, or imagine if your model changes, it is certainly *easier* to simply implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the model and expose it to the view. Programmers are lazy by nature, therefore in order to save hassle, you'll see method 1 just as much as method 2.

But that **isn't** a bad thing.

> Is one way more "correct" than the other way? Or am I just doing it wrong and over complicating it?

Remember, the MVVM design pattern is just a pattern. Neither options are *correct*, it's mostly down to the developers preference how they choose to approach the implementation of the pattern, as long as the main MVVM concepts are there, that's all that matters.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very complete answer. I appreciate it. What I was afraid of as I continued my project was running into your downside for method 2. It started to look like my code was getting messy and hard to control. Before I continued I wanted to see if I could maybe refactor it into something simpler. When I stumbled on the xamarin sample I thought their code looked very clean and easy to follow. So, in an odd way Im leaning toward refactoring more toward a method 1 approach but not out of laziness lol.

Comment: I agree, method 2 is quite a purist approach whereas method 1 is just easier to manage. You'll find your own style and preference as you go on. Good luck!